# libgdx: uniform color not sent down to fragment shader

Tags: opengl, libgdx, glsl

I have a very simple shader that uses a custom shader program.  I'm sending down the camera transformation, the world transformation as uniforms, which all work.  I'm also sending down a uniform color the same way, but it doesn't seem to affect the color on the screen.  Using `set()`  it only comes out black like the color isn't being set correctly.

Code from the libgdx shader:

```
protected final int u_projTrans = register(new Uniform("u_projTrans"));
protected final int u_worldTrans = register(new Uniform("u_worldTrans"));
protected final int u_color = register(new Uniform("u_color"));

@Override
public void begin(Camera camera, RenderContext context) {
    program.begin();
    context.setDepthTest(GL20.GL_LEQUAL, 0f, 1f);
    context.setDepthMask(true);
    set(u_projTrans, camera.combined);
}

@Override
public void render(Renderable renderable) {
    set(u_worldTrans, renderable.worldTransform);

    set(u_color, 1, 1, 1); // binding, but no change in color
    // program.setUniformf("u_color", 1, 1, 1); // works

    renderable.meshPart.render(program);
}
```

Looking at the above code, I bind u_projTrans in the begin() function and I bind u_worldTrans in the render() function.  I know those are both working based on the image I see.

Vertex shader:

```
attribute vec3 a_position;
uniform mat4 u_projTrans;
uniform mat4 u_worldTrans;

void main() {
    gl_Position = u_projTrans * u_worldTrans * vec4(a_position, 1.0);
}
```

Fragment shader:

```
uniform vec3 u_color;

void main() {
    gl_FragColor = vec4(u_color, 1); // hard-coding this to a color works, so the value in u_color seems to be (0,0,0)
}
```

When I try to set the color uniform it says it's correctly binding, but I just don't get any change in color like the value is set to (0,0,0).  However, using `program.setUniformf()` works.  Using `set()` I'm binding it exactly as I am for the others so I don't know what's different besides sending it down as a `vec3` instead of a `mat4`.

Does anyone know why the values I pass in `set(u_color, 1, 1, 1)` don't make it down to the shader?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you call `set(u_color, 1, 1, 1);` you are using the `set(Uniform, int, int int)` method. What you want is the `set(Uniform, float, float, float)` method so use `set(u_color, 1f, 1f, 1f)` instead.

Comment: That fixed it.  I was confused as I thought it might be interpreting it as an int and tried a higher value like 1000, but it was still black.  I didn't realize it would just fail silently.  Thanks!